# Pass pointer to an instance with virtual methods from C# to C++ DLL without DLL's source updates

Tags: c#, c++, dll, marshalling

I have a C++ DLL that has SetTrace() API for progress reporting requiring a pointer to a instance implementing IReporter.
Updating the C++ source code is not an option.

Both are defined in the C++ as:

```
void __stdcall SetTrace(int level, IReporter *reporter);

class IReporter
{
  public:
    virtual void SetProgress(int iProgress) = 0;
    virtual void SetMessage(const char* pszMsg) = 0;
};
```

I need to create a C# wrapper that uses the DLL's SetTrace().
Could you please give me an idea of marshaling such methods from C# to C++?

The tricky point is the virtual methods and the v-table management ...
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried doing a Google search for accessing C++ DLLs from C#? There's lots of examples and information out there. Or at least you can search this site: `[c#] call C++ DLL` or something similar.

Comment: I am able to create wrapper passing various other types from C# to C++ DLL. But passing this one (class with methods) I could not ...